# Unit testing a compnent that is getting data from Angular Behavior Subject

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine, behaviorsubject

I have this service called `EmployeeService` where I am using Angular's `BehaviorSubject` to get data from an api. I'm subcribing to this `BehaviorSubject` from another component which I am trying to test now. But because I'm unable to mock the data from the service mentioned above, the unit test is not working.

This is a bare bones of the `EmployeeService`:

```
class EmployeeService extends ApiService {
  public isEmployeeSub: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  someMethod() {
    this.isEmployeeSub.next(true);
  }

  // other methods
}
```

Now this is the component I'm trying to test. Please note that this is a huge component but I'm just showing the most important part which is needed for this component to work and that is the `isEmployee` data coming from `EmployeeService`.

```
class SalaryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  private employeeService: EmployeeService;

  employee: EmployeeModel;
  employeeSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(employeeService: EmployeeService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;

    this.employeeSubscription = this.employeeService.isEmployee.subscribe(isEmployee: boolean => {
      
      if (!isEmployee) {
        // I want this part to run at some tests and not at the others.
        return;
      }

      // do some other things
    });
}
```

The above component is subscribing to `BehaviorSubject` in `EmployeeService`, gets the data if it an employee and runs some other things. If not `isEmployee` then it returns. I want that conditional in subscribe to run at some tests and not at the others.

```
describe('SalaryComponent', () => {
  let component: SalaryComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SalaryComponent>;
  let isEmployeeSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  let mockEmployeeService: jasmine.SpyObj<EmployeeService>;  


  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockEmployeeService = jasmine.createSpyObj<EmployeeService>(
      'EmployeeService', 
      [], 
      {
        isEmployeeSub: isEmployeeSubject
      }
    );

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [],
      providers: [],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SalaryComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  fit('should show drop down if it is employee', async ()  => {
     mockEmployeeService.isEmployeeSub.next(true);
  }

  fit('should not show drop down if it is employee', async ()  => {
     mockEmployeeService.isEmployeeSub.next(false);
  }
}
```

This is how I wrote a test previously with `ReplaySubject`. That works perfectly fine. But this one doesn't seem to work. The value `isEmployee` is always false somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your not using the asynchronous features correctly.
Do not use the javascript `async`.

The easiest way is to use `fakeAsync` this way:

```
fit('should show drop down if it is employee', fakeAsync(()  => {
  mockEmployeeService.isEmployeeSub.next(true);

  tick(); // triggers subscribes
  expect(...).toBe(...);
});

fit('should not show drop down if it is employee', fakeAsync(()  => {
  mockEmployeeService.isEmployeeSub.next(false);

  tick(); // triggers subscribes
  expect(...).toBe(...);
});
```

2nd issue, your `isEmployeeSubject` is shared among all your tests. So in your second test from above, what happens is `isEmployeeSubject` remembers the `true` value from previous test. So in your component constructor, the subscribe first triggers with a `true`.
Then, you run your test, and do a `.next(false)`, which re-triggers your subscribe. Result: your subscribe has both been triggered with `true` and `false` value.
Solution:
Reset the BehaviorSubject in your beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  isEmployeeSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  mockEmployeeService = jasmine.createSpyObj<EmployeeService>(
    'EmployeeService', 
    [], 
    {
      isEmployeeSub: isEmployeeSubject
    }
  );
  // ...
```

Comment: No still the same :(

Comment: can you show the test not working then ? In your post, you only wrote the "next", there is no expect etc... What makes you know it doesn't work ?

Comment: Oh, I think I spotted the issue... Editing answer